# Programatically give value to Facebook search input so it returns suggestions box

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to give Facebook search a value programatically and it refresh and opens the suggestions box just like the user typed in the value.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" class="hiddenInput" value="hello">
  <div class="innerWrap">
     <div class="_5861 navigationFocus textInput _5eaz" id="u_r_2">
     <input type="text" class="_5eay" disabled="1" aria-hidden="1" value="XXXX"> 
     <input type="text" class="_1frb" name="q" value="hello" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Facebook" data-testid="search_input" role="combobox" aria-label="Search" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="typeahead_list_u_r_1" aria-activedescendant="js_ail"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried setting the value in the console by using `$0.setAttribute('value', 'hello')` but it doesn't start the suggestions process.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe they use change/click event. Did you try triggering it?

Comment: I tried it like this: `$($0).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 71, which: 13}));` . Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I meant just do .change() or .click() on the input field so it triggers what ever facebook do when you start typing in the search box.

Comment: No luck with `$($0).click()` or `$($0).change()` :/ I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try execCommand. It'll call the events for you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Firs forcus the input box

```
$0.focus()
```

Then use execCommand insertText

```
document.execCommand('insertText', undefined, "Hello")
```

The only issue is that the results only show if the dropdown menu is already open. I suggest figuring out how to trigger that as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works in the console. How can I perform this task in a script with jQuery? Assume I have input element in a variable called input. `$(input).focus()` and then?

Comment: This is vanilla javascript. No jQuery necessary. If you've already focused the element then just run the second line.This command takes what ever element is currently in focus and tries to insert a text string into it. By doing that it automatically calls the relevant event handlers that Facebook is using. (See the documentation link I posted above). Also I just noticed that calling `focus()` does indeed open the dropdown menu, but ONLY when chrome dev tools is closed.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misinterpreted your question. What you probably want to do is make an extension, [a Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), for example, and use content scripts to inject your script into the page.

Comment: Note that you can also inject jQuery into the page, but I wouldn't recommend it. It'll increase page load times and `document.querySelector` is a good alternative as it also supports css selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am actually building a chrome extension and trying to achieve this in a content script. I have also already injected jQuery so it's alright. But I didn't quite understand how to achieve it after selecting the input element. I couldn't execute: `$(input).execCommand('insertText', undefined, "Hello");`. What is the proper way of achieving it?